# Having to clear the cache even though caching is turned off?

Tags: joomla-3.x, cache

On on of the Joomla sites I manage, the Cache Settings in Global Configuration -> System is set to **OFF - Caching is disabled**. However, when we make changes to the articles, it is necessary to go to System -> Clear Cache and and delete the cached files before the changes will show up.

I had turned the caching on and then back off earlier and that might have something to do with it.

Is there a setting I missed somewhere?

Comment: Are you sure this took place multiple times?

Comment: @Alexandr Yes it happened multiple times and on multiple websites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a little more research and fixed this by editing the configuration.php file. Specifically, I changed the `$cache_handler` from `'file'` to `''`. I still don't know why this works, but can confirm that the issue went away and I don't have to manually clear the cache anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Cache Cleaner from Regular Labs does the job perfect.

Not using any cache is very bad for the performance - SEO and the users.

Comment: It's matter of the site, content, and the way site is build.